# Python- Calculate this equation / expression

Tags: python, expression, equation, arithmetic-expressions

I have tried two different syntax's and when I ran the syntax's I got the mathmatical resolution in both attempts, but my quiz is wanting a specific line of code to get the result. Any idea how I'm S U P P O S E D to get python to calculate this? [image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't add pictures of code to your question. Instead ype out or copy/paste and reformat your code into your question. Read the FAQ on [ask] for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a python problem and more a maths order of operations problem.

In both examples you provide, you are adding the `1` after you divide `(5**(1/2)/2)`.

You want this:

```py
ratio = (1 + 5**(1/2)) / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this one. It will help you understand the operator order better.

```
(1+(5**(0.5)))/2
```

**Hope this helps**